# difference between string and string builder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stringbuilder

I am having doubt in whether to use string or string builder to append html elements like "div" and others in my page in mvc. Is there any other approach for this thing.

Thanks.

Comment: atleast do upvote if you like answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest and saying something unusual at the end **it really does not matter**. The differences are so small that you shouldn't care about this and you should invest the time in other things that make difference.

Check this article of Jeff where all this is explained (also in a web environment, when he was creating StackOverflow).

[Coding horror article about why does not matter how do you create strings](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html)

Comment: Great view.But can you just explain me regarding the immutable thing i just don't understand it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I read that Microsoft recommends using StringBuilder when you predict to have more then 6 concatenations.

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuilder` is the way to go. A `String` holds a reference to an immutable (fixed) string, and appending to a string is horribly inefficient. If your intention is to repeated perform appends then this is exactly what the `StringBuilder` was designed for.

Comment: Inmutable, that means any change to the string causes the runtime to create  a new string and abandone the old one.

Comment: @rob: Yeah - that's what I meant - but your explanation is much clearer!

Answer (score 2):

You should use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) if you change string a lot (add, remove, change, replace characters) because it's more efficient. If you do simply operation you should use string.

The problem with [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is that it's immutable, so operatrion

```
string text = myStringVariable + "new string"
```

causes that the new instance of the text variable will be created. If you do many operation on string class then you will have many instances of string objects.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have perform appending texts, you should always use stringbuilder.

Using string would repeatedly create new instances of a string and hence inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

check this post for the depth knowledge about : [Why to use StringBuilder over string to get better performance](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/02/why-to-user-stringbuilder-over-string.html)

Answer (score 0):

String bulider Can Be Used When More than One String to be 
concatenated.
StringBuilder which is more efficient because it does 
contain a mutable string buffer. .NET Strings are immutable 
which is the reason why a new string object is created 
every time we alter it (insert, append, remove, etc.).

Comment: Thanks.Is there a limit on hw many times in our project we can use string builder ?